# how to run .exe files from a folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to run `.exe` files from a folder using batch file, here assume that I have n number of `.exe` files, so on one click I want to execute all `.exe` files without specifying each `.exe` file in the batch.

Comment: Please post the batch file you have so far so we can narrow down the exact fix you need.

Comment: Is the order in which they are run irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in ("c:\somewhere\*.exe") do start "" "%%~fa"
```

For each file in the indicated set, execute it.

See `for /?` to get help on the command usage.

Comment: might need a halt between this loop or the CPU might get honked. depends if the apps are heavy